# Capturing TS video stream gives Invalid timestamps and Invalid DTS error messages

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I'm capturing a video stream using `ffmpeg -i "http://streaming_url.com/playlist.m3u8" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "out_put_file.mp4"`. The `m3u8`-file links a list of `.ts`-files. ffmpeg creates a `mp4`-file that works but I get a lot of error messages during the capturing process.

The error messages all look like this `[hls,applehttp @ 0x33151a0] Invalid timestamps stream=1, pts=281613600, dts=281617200, size=1628
[mp4 @ 0x333a3a0] Invalid DTS: 280717200 PTS: 280713600 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess`. Do I need to care about the error messages? Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you could try adding `ffmpeg -re ...`